# Firebase Login dont seem to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

I have this React + Redux + Firebase application.

in the store, we have a userReducer with only one state property called authed which is a boolean to trach if the user is logged or not.

I have this `config.js` file which is for configuring the firebase functions and stuff.

```
export const ref = firebase.database().ref();

export const firebaseAuth = firebase.auth;

export function login (email, pw) {
  return firebaseAuth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw)
}
```

The logic is as follows > at the beginning the authed value is false, then  we create an account using

```
export function auth(email, pw) {
  return firebaseAuth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw)
    .then(saveUser);
}
```

then in the `App.js` we have

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.removeListener = firebaseAuth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) this.props.authed_true();
      else this.props.authed_false();
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.removeListener()
  }
```

`this.props.authed_true/false` function from redux just change the authed prop of the state depending on if there is a user or not.

If authed is true, meaning we have a user there is a Redirect to some route.

Now let's get the point.

Registering a user works perfect, but when I try to use Login

```
export function login (email, pw) {
  return firebaseAuth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw)
}
```

I get a

> Error: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or
>   unreachable host) has occurred.

and my URL bar becomes

from

http://localhost:3000/login

to

http://localhost:3000/login?email=anorak%40abv.bg&password=anorak97

So why does the login() does not work? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Actions are supposed to be objects, but your `login` action creator function is returning a promise which is handled asynchronously. That is a good use case for [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk). Using that library you can change it to something like:

```
export function login (email, pw) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebaseAuth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw)
    .then(user => dispatch({ type: SIGNIN_SUCCESSFUL, payload: user }))
    .catch(err => dispatch({ type: SIGNIN_ERROR, payload: err })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not good and you should consider putting

```
firebaseAuth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) this.props.authed_true();
  else this.props.authed_false();
})
```

Inside middleware, because it's a side effect after login call, you can try something like that

```
const loginMiddleware = store => next => (action) => {
  if (action.type === GET_USER_LOGIN) {
    login(action.payload.login, action.payload.pw);
    firebaseAuth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) store.dispatch(authed_true());
      store.dispatch(authed_false())
    })
  }
  return next(action);
};

export default loginMiddleware;
```

**But** it's not a case of your problem, most likely you just have a  element in your markup and URL is changed after **Submit**, so you should try to remove the  first